# TabLayout clicked or switched

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have `TabLayout` with 2 tabs. 
I have this code:

```
mTabLayoutLogin.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
           //do something else
        }
```

Is there a way to know, when switching to a tab, that the user clicked the tab or the code switched intentionally to tab (like this code `mTabLayoutLogin.getTabAt(1).select()`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (Hacky solution) You can try combination of overriding `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and your `addOnTapSelectedListener` method, if both trigger simultaneously it is probably due to user click not by code trigger.

From the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

2. (Elegant solution) When ever called from code trigger a flag(could be boolean) as well.